# Python IF Statement, straight to ELSE

Tags: python, if-statement

I seem to have a problem with my script and I hope you guys can help me. I am just beginning with programming so please bear with me. My project is that when somebody fills in any number between 1000-1199 it has to show answer A. If it's any number between 1200-1299 it has to show answer B. But the IF and ELIF statement is not working properly. It skips both of them and goes straight to ELSE.

The script here:

```
import easygui

var1 = range(1000, 1200)
var2 = range(1200, 1300)

input = easygui.enterbox(msg="Fill in your number", title="Input1")

if input == var1:
    easygui.msgbox(msg="Answer A", title="title1")
elif input == var2:
    easygui.msgbox(msg="Answer B", title="title2")
else:
    easygui.msgbox(msg="Nothing", title="Title3")
```

Thanks in advance!

Problem solved! Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code will help you.

1. Don't use python keywords as variables in line `input`.
2. when we receive input from GUI it returns a `string`, so convert it to `int`
3. use `in` rather `==`.

   ```
   import easygui
   var1 = range(1000, 1200)
   var2 = range(1200, 1300)
   input1 = int(easygui.enterbox(msg="Fill in your number", title="Input1"))

   if input1 in var1:
       easygui.msgbox(msg="Answer A", title="title1")
   elif input1 in var2:
       easygui.msgbox(msg="Answer B", title="title2")
   else:
       easygui.msgbox(msg="Nothing", title="Title3")

   print type(input1), input1
   ```

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

using `in` statement and parse input's value to integer type: `input = int(input)`

```
import easygui

var1 = range(1000, 1200)
var2 = range(1200, 1300)

input = easygui.enterbox(msg="Fill in your number", title="Input1")
input = int(input)

if input in var1:
    easygui.msgbox(msg="Answer A", title="title1")
elif answer in var2:
    easygui.msgbox(msg="Answer B", title="title2")
else:
    easygui.msgbox(msg="Nothing", title="Title3")
```

Comment: Thank you man! It worked. Input's value had to be a integer type.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
import easygui

var1 = range(1000, 1200)
var2 = range(1200, 1300)

my_input = easygui.enterbox(msg="Fill in your number", title="Input1")

if int(my_input) in var1:
    easygui.msgbox(msg="Answer A", title="title1")
elif int(my_input) in var2:
    easygui.msgbox(msg="Answer B", title="title2")
else:
    easygui.msgbox(msg="Nothing", title="Title3")
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, I have tried it but it still won't work. Can it be that Python is not recognizing the IF statement?

Comment: I edited the code so you can try it again. Input is a reserved word so I changed it to `my_input`.